# How to set Json Document attribute in GetDynamoDB processor in nifi

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, apache-nifi

I am trying to get data from DynamoDB using GetDynamoDB processor in nifi, I have provided all the mandatory fields except Json Document attribute, I don't know what to set in that field.
[image]

Input Data :

```
{
"ProductCatalog": [
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Id": {
                    "N": "101"
                },
                "Title": {
                    "S": "Book 101 Title"
                },
                "ISBN": {
                    "S": "111-1111111111"
                },
                "Authors": {
                    "L": [
                        {
                            "S": "Author1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Price": {
                    "N": "2"
                },
                "Dimensions": {
                    "S": "8.5 x 11.0 x 0.5"
                },
                "PageCount": {
                    "N": "500"
                },
                "InPublication": {
                    "BOOL": true
                },
                "ProductCategory": {
                    "S": "Book"
                }
            }
        }
    }]
    }
```

Any one can be appreciated.

Comment: Why do people redact info that would help others?

Answer (score 3):

When you store a JSON document in DynamoDB, the JSON document you store is placed as a nested object inside a wrapper object known as a *DynamoDB Item*, which stores metadata about the document. The `Json Document attribute` lets you specify the key in the DynamoDB Item for the nested JSON document so that it can be extracted from the top-level DynamoDB Item.

Looking at the [source code for the GetDynamoDB NiFi processor](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.3.0/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-aws-bundle/nifi-aws-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/aws/dynamodb/GetDynamoDB.java#L153) shows how the value (`jsonDocument`) is used to call the AWS DynamoDB SDK, extract the JSON for the specified DynamoDB Item attribute, and create a NiFi FlowFile for the contents:

```
BatchGetItemOutcome result = dynamoDB.batchGetItem(tableKeysAndAttributes);

// Handle processed items and get the json document
List<Item> items = result.getTableItems().get(table);
for (Item item : items) {
    ItemKeys itemKeys = new ItemKeys(item.get(hashKeyName), item.get(rangeKeyName));
    FlowFile flowFile = keysToFlowFileMap.get(itemKeys);

    if ( item.get(jsonDocument) != null ) {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(item.getJSON(jsonDocument).getBytes());
        flowFile = session.importFrom(bais, flowFile);
    }

    session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS);
    keysToFlowFileMap.remove(itemKeys);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, i solved it by specifying key in json document attribute

Answer (score 1):

*Json Document attribute* is which key inside your DynamodDB item do you want to become the content for the downstream flowfile.

Current, there is no way to only return the entire 'root' DynamoDB item, only inside attributes.

Below an example flow:

[image]

DynamoDB Table:

[image]

GetDynamoDB:

[image]

Inside the GenerateFlowFile I'm creating a FlowFile with the attributes *hash_key* and *range_key*.

If I configure the *Json Document attribute* as `json` the output FlowFile content would be `{"key1":"name","key2":2}`.

If I configure as `attribute` the output would be `"attribute"`.